# Почему цвет автозаполнения в safari отличается от указанного в стилях?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

Всем привет. Есть форма, в которую можно ввести email, и если пользователь существует - автозаполнить данные. В firefox, chrome все работает корректно, но в safari меняется цвет текста, причем в стилях указан нужный, а тот, что отображается, даже не указан) Не очень понимаю, как с этим бороться. Если эта информация понадобиться, то делаю на react + mui v4.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить этот стиль к инпутам

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: #071B3F;
opacity: 1; /* для iOS */
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262158/disabled-input-text-color-on-ios

Comment: Да, это сработало! Спасибо. Я только через 20 часов смогу присудить вознаграждение)